# String in WHERE query

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

So I have this problem that gives me headache. appreciate if anyone can help me solve this.

I'm using Coldfusion with MSSQL together with MySQL. The MSSQL database is the main datasource for this application that i'm working on right now. While MySQL is used for the employee database (it was created to develop employee's database with PHP). I have to connect to it in order to make this application work.

The MySQL tables:

TBL_EMPLOYEE

```
+---------+------------------+-------------------|
|EMP_ID   |    EMP_NUMBER    |    DATE_OF_BIRTH  |
+---------+------------------+-------------------|
| 1       |    00001         |    2009-01-01     |
| 2       |    00002         |    2009-01-15     |
| 3       |    TEMP01        |    2009-05-10     |  
| 4       |    TEMP02        |    2010-02-04     |
| 5       |    0006          |    2010-03-01     |
+---------+------------------+-------------------|
```

TBL_CHILD

```
+---------+------------------+---------------------|
|EMP_ID   |    CHILD_ID      |    DATE_OF_BIRTH    |

+---------+------------------+---------------------|
| 1       |    1             |    2008-11-12       |
| 1       |    2             |    2010-10-06       |
| 2       |    3             |    2009-05-10       |
| 5       |    4             |    2010-02-16       |
| 5       |    5             |    2012-03-08       |
+---------+------------------+---------------------|
```

This application will check a staff's DOB. If he has kids, the system will display his eldest child's DOB. Otherwise (if he doesn't have kids) the system will display his own DOB.

Here is the problem:

```
<cfquery name="getEmployee" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
    SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NUMBER,DATE_OF_BIRTH
    FROM   TBL_EMPLOYEE
    WHERE   EMP_NUMBER = '#users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#'
</cfquery>

<cfset mysql_id = getEmployee.EMP_ID>

<cfquery name="getChild" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
    SELECT *
    FROM   TBL_CHILD
    WHERE  EMP_ID =#mysql_id#
    ORDER BY DATE_OF_BIRTH ASC
    LIMIT 1
</cfquery>


Note : 
#users.EMP_NO[mainRow]# --> loop query from MSSQL
EMP_NUMBER = string
EMP_ID = integer (auto)
```

This query works when the employee number is numbers (i.e: 001, 101, 23002, etc)
(without the '' symbol )

```
<cfquery name="getEmployee" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
    SELECT *
    FROM    TBL_EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EMP_NUMBER = #users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#
</cfquery>

<cfset mysql_id = getEmployee.EMP_ID>

<cfquery name="getChild" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
    SELECT *
    FROM   TBL_CHILD
    WHERE  EMP_ID =#mysql_id#
</cfquery>
```

But it gives me error when employee number is character (TEMP101, TEMP007, etc).

```
 '#users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#'
```

I have tried to use the same query in phpmyadmin, it works just fine. Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to solve this?

**(Update from comments)**
The error message is:

> Error Executing Database Query. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 3 SELECT * FROM TBL_CHILD WHERE
>   EMP_ID =

Comment: Where does it give you an error and *what is the error*? And at the very least you ought not be hard-coding your dynamic values into your SQL string, you should be passing them as parameters. This, though, is just what you should be doing as a matter of course, and probably doesn't contribute to your current problem. If you update your question with useful error info, I'll remove my down-vote, and try to help you out...

Comment: @AdamCameron : Error Executing Database Query.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

 SELECT * FROM TBL_CHILD WHERE EMP_ID =

Comment: if emp number is a string your where clause should always be `WHERE EMP_NUMBER = '#users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#'` even if you're passing a number to avoid datatype miss-match errors. what is the value of #users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#? does the value include a single quote, i.e. '101', and not 101.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the error is caused by the difference of EMP_NUMBER in MSSQL and MySQL.

eg:

```
EMP NUMBER in MSSQL = 080, but in MySQL is stored as 80. 

EMP NUMBER in MSSQL = 070, but in MySQL is stored as 70.
```

so to solve this, what i do is just to trim the **mysql_id**

```
<cfset mysql_id =rereplace(mysql_id,'^0+','','ALL')>
```

Thanks for all answers and am very sorry for the irrelevant question.

Comment: It wasn't an irrelevant question. But this is a workaround/hacked solution. yes it will prevent your first query from returning 0 records and should be done anyway to make the data match; however, the second query isn't even required.  getEmployee and getChild are directly related and can be run joining the two queries. Being that you may need information out of the employee table if nothing is returned from the child table, you would use a left join instead of an inner join.

Answer (score 3):

These mySQL queries should be joined instead of hitting the database twice for every employee.  It will solve your second query causing an error, then you only need to worry about this query returning 0 results.

Something like

```
<cfquery name="getEmployee" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
  SELECT 
    [only the columns you need from both tables]
  FROM 
    TBL_EMPLOYEE
    inner join tbl_child on tbl_employee.emp_id = tbl_child.emp_id
  WHERE 
    tbl_employee.EMP_NUMBER = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#users.EMP_NO[mainRow]#">
</cfquery>
```

You could also get all the employees back in one query using `in`

```
WHERE 
        tbl_employee.EMP_NUMBER in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#valueList(users.EMP_NO)#" list="yes">)
```

Comment: I did, aside from changing the inner join to a left join, the answer is still accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `getEmployee` may not return data sometimes. Thus, in your second query `#mysql_id#` will output nothing. To remedy this you can place quotation marks and use the following query:

```
<cfquery name="getChild" datasource="#mysqlDB#">
SELECT *
FROM TBL_CHILD
WHERE EMP_ID = '#mysql_id#'
</cfquery>
```

Of course, this only addresses the runtime error, but you are most likely facing data issues as well.

Comment: Better yet, use a query param.  Even better, use a single query of queries instead of all that looping.

Comment: that seems silly.  let the DB do DB work. no point making CF store a whole table to do a qoq when you can do a `join` and `in`.

Comment: @Travis - you appear to have missed the part where he said that there are not only two dbs, but two db types, sql server and mysql.  In order for your suggestion to work, the mysql server would have to be added to sql server as a linked server.  Given my experience with that sort of thing, I recommend it.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk the 2 queries that are in the question are using the same datasource, join those 2 queries and use `IN valueList(users.EMP_NO)` per my suggested answer (users is his msSQL query). no qoq required.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your follow-up comment detailing the actual error:

> @AdamCameron : Error Executing Database Query. You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 SELECT *
>   FROM TBL_CHILD WHERE EMP_ID =

It suggests to me you've given us a slightly bum steer as to where the situation lies. It's not with `EMP_NUMBER`, it's related to `EMP_ID`. This is why it's important to not simply *describe* the situation, it's important to give the actual error messages (and, indeed, actually pay attention to them... because they tell you what the problem is ;-)

The problem here is that you have alpha-numeric EMP_IDs, which means you need to *quote* the value, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_CHILD
WHERE EMP_ID = '#mysql_id#'
```

Although you should not do this, as I alluded to in my initial comment. You should *always* pass dynamic data values as parameters, not hard-coding them in the SQL.  So it should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_CHILD
WHERE EMP_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#mysql_id#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR"> <!--- I'm guessing at VARCHAR --->
```

Also, @Candide could well be right (in fact almost certainly is!)... if the query that `mysql_id` comes from is empty, then `mysql_id` will be an empty string, which is also invalid here. You need to check for that.

Lastly... don't use `SELECT *`. Specify the columns you actually want (and *only* the columns you actually want). This is not related to your problem, it's just "good practice".

Comment: `EMP_ID = integer (auto)` so cfsqltype would need to be numeric or integer. Hence he has no ' around the value. this may prevent the runtime error (I don't remember how mySql handles numbers being treated like strings) but will not address the first query from returning no results.

Comment: Yeah true, I kinda stopped reading what was in the original question beyond a point. Definitely points to @Candide's answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "it certainly points towards what @candide says the problem is being caused by". Yes, not having multiple queries is a better approach to the *solution* to the problem. And, indeed, in general.

Comment: As Adam mentioned, that is *not* what your error message says. The message says the error occurs in the `getChild` query on the `emp_id` column. That could easily happen if your first query returned 0 records. (Does it?) If so your code would pass an empty string "" into the where clause, creating an invalid sql statement ie `WHERE EMP_ID = (nothing here is invalid)`. That said, I agree a `join` seems more apropriate here. But .. I also think it is important to understand *why* your code is failing.

Comment: (My response above was in reply to a comment which has since disappeared ...)